# Is it instance name/id that scala REPL prints?

Tags: scala, scala-repl

[Tutorial](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/set-class.html) mentions about mutable sets in the initial but why would the REPL change the instance name from `res4` to `res5` when a new element is added? Is 'res' not the instance name that REPL prints? Below is the code in context. Beginner in scala. Please bear if the question is trivial.

```scala
scala> val set = scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]()
val set: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set()

scala> set += 1
val res0: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1)

scala> set += 2 += 3
val res1: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: No, the REPL prints the variable names. It generates new names for the unnamed expressions. Multiple variables can point to the same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reference did not change though, it means `res0 == res1`. Scala repl will generate names for expressions that are not assigned any name, no matter if it's mutable or not.

Additionally take a look at the [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Set.html#+=(elem:A):Growable.this.type). For `mutable.Set`, the method `+=` results in `Set.this.type`. Since there is a value returned, it has to be assigned some name.